PIC16F18325 communicating with ESP32 DEVKIT through EUSART not working
So, I have been trying to get this to work for the past couple of days and I just can't seem to find the issue. I used the same code with the Curiosity Nano PIC and it "echoed" to the MQRTT Server perfectly fine but I switch to my PIC and it won't "echo" to the MQTT Server. Here is the code I used for both. I am using MPLAB x IDE v6.15 also.
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/i2c1_master.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/eusart.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/examples/i2c1_master_example.h"

uint8_t rxData;

void Custom_EUSART_Receive_ISR(void) {

    EUSART_Receive_ISR();  
    if (EUSART_is_rx_ready()) {
        rxData = EUSART_Read();
    while (!EUSART_is_tx_ready())
    EUSART_Write(rxData);
    while (!EUSART_is_tx_done());
    }
    }
int main(void) {

    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    I2C1_Initialize();
    EUSART_SetRxInterruptHandler(Custom_EUSART_Receive_ISR);
    INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();
    INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();
    
 int ii = 0;
    float value;
   
    while (1) {
        ii++;
        if (ii >= 100) 
        {
            ii == 0;
        }
       value = (float)ii / 10.0;
       printf("%4d %.2f\r", ii, value);
        __delay_ms(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}

   


I ran the code on both PIC's and it worked (just counting by 1 and displaying the number along with the number divided by 10 (per class assignment)) on the Curiosity nano but not my PIC16F18325. The curiosity nano uses the PIC18F47Q10.

Issues like yours are typically hidden in the details of how you used the MCC code generator to create the interfaces to the peripherals. If you actually want to know what seems wrong you will need to learn how to use MPLABX to "package" a project in a ZIP archive, then attach it to your question.
